# Sorting shuffled dates - Counting or Radix?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, counting, radix-sort

I'm trying to solve this problem:

There is a shuffled list of the n most important events from year 0 to the end of the second millennium (year 2000).

What is the most efficient way to sort the list, when all the events of the same year are sorted in the list (for example, event form January 2014 comes before an event from February 2014, and the events don't have to be in adjacent indexes)?

I understand I should use a stable algorithm, and the answer depends on n: if n is bigger than some number, I should use radix, else I should use counting. But I don't know how to show it formally.

I also know that if the range of the years is much bigger than the linear time, than radix is preferable.

Comment: You can't know for sure / prove which one will be more efficient for any given dataset unless you know the exact constant factors involved, which will be both machine and data dependent (not just the size of the dataset, but also the distribution of the elements).

Comment: You could do a partial radix sort (just sorting by year) since you know that day and month is already sorted.

Comment: I believe the whole point of this exercise is to be able to reduce any set of dates, to a problem of at most 2000 elements. Values for the same year are already sorted, so all you have to do is find the 1st index of each year and sort those, hence you can always solve it in linear time irrespectively of the sorting algorithm.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by counting sort. In some cases, a "counting" sort generates a set of counts, then creates a new array based on the counts, ignoring whatever was in the original array. A radix sort includes a counting pass, after which the counts are converted into starting indices for each logical bucket, and this is probably what you wan to use for this data.